# Can we calclulate R0 from logistic fit

Tags: logistic, optimization

Suppose we are fitting covid19 data with logistic function,

$$\dot N(t)=rN(t)(1-\frac{N(t)}{K})$$

and get a good fit.

Can we get [R0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_reproduction_number) from the optimal value of $r$ and $K$ ? If yes, how to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SIR model is slightly different and follows the following differential equation*:

$$\dot{u}(t) = u(t) \left( C_1 - \gamma \ln u(t)+ x_0 \beta^\prime u(t) \right)  $$

where

- $S(t)$, $I(t)$, $R(t)$ are transforms of $u(t)$ following:

  $$\begin{array}{}
  S(t) &=& x_0 u\\
  I(t) &=& \frac{\gamma}{\beta^\prime} \ln u(t) - x_0 u(t) - \frac{C_1}{\beta^\prime} \\
  R(t) &=& - \frac{\gamma}{\beta^\prime} \ln u(t)
  \end{array}$$
- Also of interrest is $Q(t) = I(t) + R(t)$ which is the total of people that got sick (since the logisitic fit does not differentiate between infected and recovered)

  $$Q(t) = - \frac{C_1}{\beta^\prime} - x_0 u(t)$$
- The constant $C_1$ is an integration constant that can be fixed based on the boundary condition $S(t) + I(t) + R(t) = N$ where $N$ is the total people.

  $$C_1 = -\beta^\prime N$$
- The constant $x_0$ is another boundary/starting condition and relates to the initial number of recovered people $R(0)$

  $$x_0 = N e^{\frac{\beta\prime}{\gamma}R(0)}$$

  If we start with zero recovered people then

  $$x_0 = N$$
- We introduced the term $\beta^\prime$ because the differential equations for the SIR model [can be written differently](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/460607/164061) with a scaling $N$. The work of Harko, Lobo and Mak does not use the scaling with $N$ which makes the interpretation of $\beta$ different. We use $\beta^\prime$ for the parameter used in Harko, Lobo and Mak. We can transform as:

  $$\beta^\prime = \frac{\beta}{N}$$

If $R(0) = 0$ and consequently $x_0 = 1$, then we can rewrite this as:

$$\frac{\dot{S}(t)}{S(t)} =  -\beta \left( 1 + \frac{\gamma}{\beta} \ln \frac{S(t)}{N} - \frac{S(t)}{N} \right)$$

or in terms of $Q(t)$

$$\frac{\dot{Q}(t)}{Q(t)} =  \beta \left(1 - \frac{Q(t)}{N} - \frac{\gamma}{\beta} \left(1- \frac{N}{ Q(t)}\right) \ln \left(1- \frac{ Q(t)}{N}\right)   \right)$$
which looks a bit like the equation for the logistic growth (the last term is different and becomes zero when $\gamma = 0$)

$$\frac{\dot{Q}(t)}{Q(t)} = r\left(1  - \frac{Q(t)}{K}\right) \hphantom{- \frac{\gamma}{\beta} \left(1- \frac{N}{ Q(t)}\right) \ln \left(1- \frac{ Q(t)}{N}\right) }$$

---

*Harko, Lobo and Mak *2014 Exact analytical solutions of the Susceptible-Infected-Recovered (SIR) epidemic model and of the SIR model with equal death and birth rates* https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.2160

---

So you could see logistic growth as a special case of the SIR model with $\gamma = 0$ (no recovery) and $R_0 =\infty$.

Therefore based on logistic fits you can not derive the value of $R_0$ since a logistic fit is a SIR fit with fixed $R_0$.

Note that, when $Q(t) << N$ then for both the SIR model and the logistic model you get approximately exponential growth.

For the SIR model you get $\left(1- \frac{N}{ Q(t)}\right) \ln \left(1- \frac{ Q(t)}{N}\right)  \approx 1$ and

$$ \frac{\dot{Q}(t)}{Q(t)} = \beta - \gamma$$

for the logistic growth model you get

$$ \frac{\dot{Q}(t)}{Q(t)} = r $$

So fits with a logistic model, or anything else that has initial exponential growth, to data in an early phase, may be used to determine $\beta - \gamma$, but *not* the value of $R_0 = \frac{\beta}{\gamma}$ which requires data over a longer period.

(If it is covid-19 that you are after, then an $R_0$ value with more data will be wrong since the data does not relate to an SIR model which is a model for homogeneous mixing and parameters that are not changing in time)

Comment: great answer and really want to thank you for helping me to derive these. I think I need to read more books instead of searching online blogs. Many of the blogs are inaccurate on SIR model. BTW, do you have some Epidemiology background? or just strong at statistics and math?

Comment: @HaitaoDu I moved to studying Food Technology after a bsc in Astronomy. But I am still strong in math. Now I am modelling transport of aroma instead of transport of starlight. And it turns out that modelling food is much harder than modelling stars.

Comment: I have been working on "machine learning" and statistics for couple of years. I never fully understand differential equations because it seems statistics model is different kind of model. Until recent I work on this covid19 and I re-learned these differential equation stuff, thank you very much for all the knowledge and insights.

Comment: @HaitaoDu I believe that there is an interesting connection between differential equations and statistics when we take the thermodynamic limit (an infinite number of particles and related volume). For instance, diffusion, which can be explained with differential equations, is actually a probability process. When you get a puncture in your tire then the flow due to the leak is simply a matter of chance (there is a tiny probability that a punctured tire could inflate). The normal distribution also follows a nice differential equation that relates to diffusion $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t} x =-tx$.