# How can we modify SIR model to account multiple waves of infection?

Tags: modeling, differential-equations

We had a very [nice discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/446712/fitting-sir-model-with-2019-ncov-data-doesnt-conververge) for modeling covid19 data with SIR model. If we monitor number of infected cases over time,  most of these models will only have one wave.

How can we modify the model to be able to capture multiple waves?

For example, following trend (number of infected in IRAN)

[image]

Comment: Surely making $R_0$, the reproduction rate, to be a function $R(t)$ would do this. Allowing $R(t)$ to increase and decrease then increase again (and so on) would give us waves surely?

Comment: @jcken yes, thanks for the comment, basically we can make $\beta$ and $\gamma$ changing over time.